# Randomly Killing AIs in PCF

Tags: artificial-intelligence, pcf, chaos

I am trying to find a way to test an application's resiliency HA capabilities by randomly killing application instances.  I have not yet tried any service/commands. 
 Is there an app/service that does this (like Chaos Lemur does for VMs) that can be added to PCF as a tile?